# What are the default Etherscan readable methods?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, evm

I am deploying NFT contracts on EVM compatible networks with an "etherscan" tx scanner.

I can see that sometimes the method of the tx listed is an alphanumeric string like `0xc203b6b8`.
But for known functions the readable name is displayed like as `Mint`, `Safe Mint`, `Burn` ...

By chance I have discovered that the `DeleteRecord()` function of my Solidity contract is shown as `Delete Record` but this doesn't work for functions like `NewRecord()`, `SaveRecord()`, `EditRecord()`, etc...

Then I wonder if there is a list where I can know which are all the functions that Etherscan shows as readable texts for use it and make my contract more clear in the scanner.

Thank you.

PD: This is an example of readable methods in my test contract:
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x025f05b1a985f173b0d50e1ec7378d5191d56f61

Answer (score -1):

The alphanumeric string you are referring to is known as MethodID. It consists of the first 4 bytes of the hash of the method name and parameters.

There is a database where you can check signatures: https://www.4byte.directory.

Yet, it probably won't contain your signatures as your contracts aren't probably indexed by the database.

To find your MethodIDs use this documentation:
https://solidity-by-example.org/function-selector/

Nevertheless, verifying your contract enables most scanners to show your methods by name.

Comment: I know the names of the MethodID of my contracts. What I want to know is what Solidity  function names does Etherscan recognize and show after as a readable text like "Mint", "Transfer" or surprising to me "Delete Record"

Comment: @JTConsulta Have you verified your contract?

Comment: I have not verified my contract. I am on a test network.

Comment: @JTConsulta Are you on a public or private test network? If its public like Rinkeby, you can indeed verify the contract.